# Modify json script to keep one of the duplicate value based on id

Tags: python, json

I have a json file containing:

```
[{"id": "0",
"Name": "John",
"Blah": "m",
...
...}
{
"id": "2",
"Name": "John",
"Blah", "m",
...
...},
{
"id": "1",
"Name": "Ron",
"Blah", "r",
...
...},
{
"id": "0",
"Name": "Jake",
"Blah", "s",
...
...}]
```

As you can everything else is same beside the id's. What I want to do I would like to keep the one with id=2 and delete the one with id=0.

So, after modification file should look like:

```
[{
"id": "2",
"Name": "John",
"Blah", "m",
...
...},
{
"id": "1",
"Name": "Ron",
"Blah", "r",
...
...},
{
"id": "0",
"Name": "Jake",
"Blah", "s",
...
...}]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
with open(filename+'.json') as f:
    # load json objects to dictionaries
    jsons = map(json.loads, f)

uniques = {x['Name']: x for x in jsons}

# write to new json file
with open(filename+"Output"+'.json' ,'w') as nf:
    json.dump(uniques.values(), nf)

print uniques.values()
```

Above x contains the list. I am not able to figure out how I can iterate over the tuple elements.

But it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readJsonFile.py", line 18, in <module>
    uniques = {x['PlayerName']: x for x in jsons}
  File "readJsonFile.py", line 18, in <dictcomp>
    uniques = {x['PlayerName']: x for x in jsons}
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I tried looking for an example on stackoverflow. Also, tried to change the x to an int or string. Doesn't work, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So it is *purely* the `Name` key that is to be used? Or also the `Blah` key?

Comment: The error tells you that `jsons` is a *list of lists*, not a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Perhaps you need to look closely at what `jsons` contains. The error tells you that `x` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: In other words, the *input format posted here* does not accurately reflect your actual data.

Comment: Umm.. I am loading the json file which has that information. "..." means more keys and values. All I am trying to do is delete that duplicate

Comment: You are loading a file with one JSON object per line: `jsons = map(json.loads, f)`. **At least one** of those results is not a dictionary.

Comment: The format you posted can't actually be loaded in that manner, you have a complete JSON object on each line (the [JSON Lines format](http://jsonlines.org/)). What you posted has way too many newlines.

Comment: Thanks got it to work, dictionary wasn't needed. I loaded it via 
`d = json.load(f)` and got it to work.

Comment: Right, so you had **one** long object?

Comment: yes, had list of lists, where I should have simply loaded a list and printed unique elements

Thanks a lot for pointing it out. Sorry took little longer to head into my head :)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, Don't think I can post the solution to my own answer.

Code is here:

`with open(filename+'.json') as f:

    d = json.load(f)


uniques = {str(x['Name']): x for x in d}
print "unique vals:",uniques
`

Comment: You can post a solution to your own question - it's actually better than leaving a question open. (So people know not to try and solve it).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martijn Pieters

Solution is:

```
#Opening File
with open(filename+'.json') as f: 
    d = json.load(f) 
#Printing Unique data 
uniques = {str(x['Name']): x for x in d} 
print "unique vals:",uniques
```